# kernel panic - diagnosis?

Tags: kernel

I'm having a kernel panic problem - my machine will run for hours, maybe all day and then have a panic attack.  I have no idea how to interpret the output, but here's a picture of what's left on the screen when it happens:

[image: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/13279067/photo.JPG] 
I've looked through the logs but didn't find anything obvious - I'm still learning though so I've probably missed something.  It's a little harder since it's always happened when I've been out or at night so I can't pinpoint the exact time it crashed.

Anyone have advice?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a kernel bug, so I suggest filing a bug report in LaunchPad against the linux package, attach the image to the bug report.  Also, run `apport-collect` and specify the bug number so the kernel developers can get enough machine specific info to help them fix the bug.

See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Bugs for more details on how to file a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Little late and maybe irrelevant as you don't state what version of ubuntu you are running but you don't happen to have xtables-addons installed on 12.10 do you? I was having a similar problem and tried to resolve it by a process of elimination, removing that package seems to have done it.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that certain parts of your RAM are corrupted. Try running the memtest86+ utility overnight (you can access it when you're starting Ubuntu, on the GRUB stage - if you get no menu, press Esc).

Here's a blog post that describes it: [linky](http://justinsomnia.org/2009/03/ubuntu-crashing-randomly-run-memtest86/)